# List and dictionary in one linq query(not subquery) c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _smartBoostItems.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (var condition in _levelConditionsDict)
    {
        if (_smartBoostItems[i].progression_to_finish >= level.PercentsLeftToLevelCompleteWhileTurnType
            && _smartBoostItems[i].condition 
            && _smartBoostItems[i].condition_id == condition.Key)
        {
            _availibleSmartBoosts.Add(_smartBoostItems[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

`_smartBoostItems` - it's a `List<SmartBoostLibItem>`
`_levelConditionsDict` - it's a `Dictionary<int, int>`

How can I convert this code to a linq query? Or maybe it will be worse? I don't like this nested loops, there are not too much elements. There will be about 500 iterations.

Comment: Even LINQ would use loops, you just won't see them

Comment: Could you please explain what your code is trying to do? We are doing this for free, and it will make this far easier for us then having to wade through your code.

Comment: No matter what fancy framework you put on your code, you still have to evaluate all the combinations of items. Unless there is a performance issue, you should be asking `"What is easier to read and maintain?"` If there is a performance issue, then you need to ask how you can get the same information without inspecting all of the combinations of all the items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query which is more efficient:

```
_availibleSmartBoosts = _smartBoostItems
    .Where(i=> i.progression_to_finish >= level.PercentsLeftToLevelCompleteWhileTurnType
          && i.condition && _levelConditionsDict.ContainsKey(i.condition_id))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: one advantage of this is it will short circuit if the first conditions are false, so ContainsKey will not have to be executed.

Comment: @YairHalberstadt The `if` statement from the original question would also skip out at the first condition it meets that is not true.

Comment: Thanks, thats i was looking for.